# ionic cordova run ios - nothing happens

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to deploy my Ionic app to an iPhone by running either of these commands:

```
ionic cordova run ios
ionic cordova run ios --device
```

The console displays the following text:

```
[OK] Your app has been deployed.
Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

If we look at the console output everything seems to be fine, but my iPhone doesn't detect anything and the application doesn't run. I managed to get it on my phone by opening the workspace file inside the platforms/ios and running it with Xcode, but that's a pretty tedious process, and I'm sure that's not the way to go, as it doesn't support livereload.

Also, I tried to start a new project and I'm having the same issue, so I guess it's not any plugin's fault.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: have you tried with `--verbose`?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the app from Xcode, does Xcode give you any more error messages in its output window? This may be a signing issue.

Answer (score 0):

same error here from console.

with --verbose

get this message
registerShutdownFunction.process.exit/normal shutdown